# use php session to list multiple form input

Tags: php

I am new to php. How can I use session to remember my multiple form input like this:
In the first webpage, I can input for example a product name, when I click submit, the second page can tell me the product name I typed in. AND, if I go back to the first page again, and input another product name, and click submit, the second page can display the first product and the new product. If I input more product names continuously in this way, I can see all products listed in the second page. 
How can I use session to do this?

First page (order.html):

```
<html><body>
<h4>Order Form</h4>
<form action="showorder.php" method="post"> 
Product name: <input name="prodname" type="text" /> 
<input type="submit" />
</form>
</body></html>
```

Second page (showorder.php):

```
<html><body>
<?php
$Pname = $_POST['prodname'];
echo "You ordered ". $Pname . ".<br />";
?>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the $_SESSION array in the following fashion:

```
$_SESSION['products'][] = $_POST['prodname'];
```

That means that `$_SESSION['products']` will be an array containing all the purchased products.

Don't forget to call `session_start()` in the beginning of all relevant pages, and filter your code against SQL injections and such.

Answer (score 0):

session_start();

$_SESSION['everthing'] = $_POST['username'];

Then you can echo out the session, or just assign a variable to it. Sessions will stay there until the browser is closed